# How to check if a value already exists in DataGridView?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am trying to check each row in the DataGridView whenever I add an Item in order to avoid duplicates. But my code only allows me to check the first data I added.

Here is my code given below:

```
For Each row In BarcodePrintListGrid.Rows

    If Label44.Text = row.Cells("Barcode ID").Value Then
        MetroMessageBox.Show(Me, "Item Already Added", "System Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

        Label47.Text = "None"
        Label44.Text = "None"
        Label42.Text = "None"
        Label31.Text = "None"
        Label40.Text = "0"
        TextBox1.Clear()

        Exit For

    Else
        BarcodePrintListGrid.Rows.Add(Label47.Text, Label44.Text, Label42.Text, Label31.Text, Label40.Text, 1)

        MetroMessageBox.Show(Me, "Item Added to List", "System Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

        Label47.Text = "None"
        Label44.Text = "None"
        Label42.Text = "None"
        Label31.Text = "None"
        Label40.Text = "0"
        TextBox1.Clear()

        Exit For
    End If

Next
```

Comment: `Exit For` will exit the `For` loop once it finds the _first_ duplicate

Comment: @o_O  what will I do in order to find the other duplicates?

Comment: Why would you want to find the rest of the duplicates? One duplicate is enough to not add the row so who cares if there are more? In fact, if you're checking for duplicates before adding then there can't possibly be another duplicate, unless data is being added another way. The thing to do is to use a flag, i.e. a `Boolean` variable. Set it to `False` initially and then start the loop. If you find a duplicate, set the flag to `True` and exit. When the loop is done, test the flag and add a row if and only if it is still `False`.

Comment: @o_O  I just used the Exit For because my code still keeps going after the duplicate has already been located and keeps adding false data

Comment: @jmcilhinney so basically, I just need to add a boolean variable and set it false and put it inside my condition if a duplicate is found and set it to True then I’ll make a condition if the boolean is still false I’ll add that data? Do I still need to erase the Exit For?

Comment: You need to do what I said to do and only what I said to do.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I’ll take that answer as to dont erase the Exit For... I’ll try it later

Comment: @jmcilhinney it works now bro... Cheers!

Comment: @jmcilhinney can you help me with this looping problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47814095/sms-code-cant-send-bulk-messages-using-reader-read-loop-and-at-commands-vb-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait until the loop has gone all the rows of your `DataGridView` before deciding to add the row to it or not.

Try with this code :

```
 Dim test As Boolean = False
    For Each row In BarcodePrintListGrid.Rows
        If Label44.Text = row.Cells("Barcode ID").Value Then
            test=true
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    if test=false then
            BarcodePrintListGrid.Rows.Add(Label47.Text, Label44.Text, Label42.Text, Label31.Text, Label40.Text, 1)

            MetroMessageBox.Show(Me, "Item Added to List", "System Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    else
            MetroMessageBox.Show(Me, "Item Already Added", "System Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    end if
     Label47.Text = "None"
     Label44.Text = "None"
     Label42.Text = "None"
     Label31.Text = "None"
     Label40.Text = "0"
     TextBox1.Clear()
```